# How would I make a file with certain content in batch?

Tags: file, batch-file

I know how to make a batch file make a file
using
`echo. 2>EmptyFile.txt`
But how would I add information to the file?
thanks

Comment: How about using an editor ?

Comment: I would like it so that when i run the Bat file it automatically makes the file with the specified code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo cmd1 > file  
echo cmd2 >> file
```

Where cmd1 or cmd2 need to be replaced by the required statements you want to have in the batch file.
( >> appends)

Comment: Well, this also adds the quotation marks and the trailing space to the file…

Comment: so just remove the quotations, it will still echo

Comment: "cmd1"  and "cmd2" is meant as placeholder for whatever command is required.

Comment: @stacker, I think you just mean the string of data you want output to the file.  The commands will not execute with the `ECHO` command at the beginning.

Comment: I know it is really easy to give an answer to a question, but in my humble opinion it would have been just as easy to find a previous question that answered the users question.